# Help page on the daily reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I just read the [bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and came across the term "daily reputation cap" which I never heard of before.

I since found some information here on meta but not in the help pages, although [it appears it was once there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62973/clarification-about-daily-cap-and-accepted-answers).

Is there any reason it's not mentioned in the help pages? Or if it is explained somewhere why isn't it linked on the bounty page?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a separate dedicated page, but there is some info about the rep cap [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination
>   of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and
>   association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the term "reputation cap" so I must have skipped over this. But I find it weird that the bounty page uses a term that doesn't exist on any other help page. Could this be changed?

Comment: @Thomas Propose something that's better than the descriptive text we currently have, and it will most likely be done. Otherwise, no.

Comment: How about this:  
You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. **This is also known as the daily reputation cap.** Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation **cap**.